# C++: Multiple definition error when including parent class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, include, multiple-definition-error

I am writing a simple banking program with derived classes and I am running into a `Multiple definition of <method name>` error when including parent class.

Keep in mind that I just started coding in C++ yesterday, and moving over from Java/PHP, handling headers/definitions is a bit confusing for me. Please correct anything you see wrong!

Here is a sample of my files/code:

**Files**

- Account.h
- Account.cpp (Super)
- ChequingAccount.cpp (Child)
- SavingsAccount.cpp (Child)

The error is reproduce-able when including the parent class (Account.cpp) into any file. I have reduced my code by a lot, but it should give you an idea of how I am handling inheritance.

To clarify, when I `#include` the child classes to any file (**ChequingAccount.cpp**) works fine, and inherited functions work as expected. However, when I `#include` the parent class (**Account.cpp**) breaks the compiler with the `Multiple definition of <method name>` error for all methods.

Again, I am not sure if this is the proper way to do it, but this is what I understand from tutorials I have found.

**Code**

*Account.h*

```
#ifndef ACCOUNT_H
#define ACCOUNT_H

class Account
{
    protected:
        double m_balance;

    public:
        Account(double balance); // Constructor.
        virtual ~Account(); // Destructor.

        // Accessor Methods.
        double getBalance() const;

        // Mutator Methods.
        virtual void withdrawFunds(double amount);
        void depositFunds(double amount);
};

#endif
```

*Account.cpp (Superclass)*

```
#include "Account.h"

Account::Account(double balance = 0)
{
    m_balance = balance;
}

Account::~Account()
{
    // TODO: Delete this data structure...
}

double Account::getBalance() const
{
    return m_balance;
}

void Account::withdrawFunds(double amount)
{
    m_balance -= amount;
}

void Account::depositFunds(double amount)
{
    m_balance += amount;
}
```

*ChequingAccount.cpp (Child)*

```
#include "Account.h"

class ChequingAccount: public Account
{
    public:
        ChequingAccount(int id, int userId, double balance) : Account(id, balance){};

        void withdrawFunds(double amount)
        {
            // Override parent method.
        }
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say *"including the parent class (Account.cpp) into any file."*? If you mean you do `#include "Account.cpp"` then that would likely be the issue.

Comment: @uesp Yes that's precisely it. What is the issue with doing that? I don't intend on using the parent class but I am wondering why there is an error when including that file? This is more of a "why" question, rather than "how can I fix this" question.

Comment: @user3745117 Did you actually do that? The posted code shows correct usage of `#include`, with the `.h` header file.

Comment: @Potatoswatter No, I don't have that in my code, but I am wondering why that gives an error when I do `#include` it.

Answer (score 2):

When you #include "some file.cpp", you are directing the compiler to copy the contents of that cpp file to that point in the program. This will create two compiled versions of your "some file" which will lead to "Multiple Definitions."

Answer (score 1):

First of all, "identical" functions declared in base class and sub-class will not cause multiple definition error.

Here is just one example and explanation aiming to help you understand my point:

main.cpp

```
class father{
    void fun();
}
void father::fun(){}

class son : public father{
    void fun();
}
void son::fun(){}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

You compile it, and definitely no multiple definition error. In Java, we define functions within classes. In C++, only inline functions are defined within classes and others are declarations, which can be declared whatever times you like. See the definition syntax : `father::fun` `son::fun`. These actually define two different functions, one is in `father` and the other is in `son`. So there are no multiple definition error. Once more, in class declarations you can only define inline functions and can only declare non-inline functions. So there are on multiple definition errors at all. This just aims to help you understand it in a grammar way.

BTW, if compiler failed to inline, there would be no multiple definition error too because even though you define inline functions in header files and include the files anywhere, inline functions are of internal linkage.

I compiled your codes and got different errors regarding your defined constructors. Anyway, including cpp files using `"include"` means you don't get the point of implementation file and interface file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the child's method as a member of the child class explicitly in the child's .cpp file as well. See below:

*ChequingAccount.cpp (Child)*

```
#include "Account.h"

class ChequingAccount: public Account
{
    public:
        ChequingAccount(int id, int userId, double balance) : Account(id, balance){};

        void ChequingAccount::withdrawFunds(double amount)
        {
            // Override parent method.
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have `void Account::withdrawFunds(double)` defined when you define `void ChequingAccount::withdrawFunds(double)`.

Try `virtual void ChequingAccount::withdrawFunds(double)`

The virtual keyword is similar to overriding in Java.

Comment: That's not true. It's different from Java and this will not cause multiple definition error. Please devise one such case and try it on your own. Actually, these two functions are in different namespace because classes are namespaces too.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you should not include a cpp file.

The reason you get a multiple definition error actually has nothing to do with class inheritance.

Consider a simple example:

add.h:

```
#ifndef __ADD_H_
#define __ADD_H_
int add(int a);
#endif
```

add.cpp:

```
#include "add.h"
int add(int a) { return a + 1; }
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "add.h"
int main() { return add(-1); }
```

The way C++ dealing with `#include` directive is simply to copy-paste the included file and replace the `#include` line. So if we expand the above files manually, we will get something like:

add.cpp:

```
#ifndef __ADD_H_
#define __ADD_H_
int add(int a);
#endif
int add(int a) { return a + 1; }
```

main.cpp:

```
#ifndef __ADD_H_
#define __ADD_H_
int add(int a);
#endif
int main() { return add(-1); }
```

which will work just fine. (We are allowed to have multiple declarations of a function)

However, if you decide to include the .cpp file instead of the .h file like the code below:

main.cpp:

```
#include "add.cpp" // notice here
int main() { return add(-1); }
```

And if you expand it as we just did:

add.cpp:

```
#ifndef __ADD_H_
#define __ADD_H_
int add(int a);
#endif
int add(int a) { return a + 1; }
```

main.cpp:

```
#ifndef __ADD_H_
#define __ADD_H_
int add(int a);
#endif
int add(int a) { return a + 1; }
int main() { return add(-1); }
```

You will see the code includes multiple definitions of the function `add`, one of which is in `add.cpp` and the other one is in `main.cpp`. When linking these two files together (each .cpp file is compiled separately using a compiler and then linked together using a linker), the linker will be confused by two definitions of `add` and doesn't know which one to use, so it will start to complain.